# Trying to get the number ascii of a var inside a loop

Tags: javascript

I need to capture the number ASCII 08 (Backspace) in that loop:

```
var texto = document.getElementById('textEnv').value;
var number = 08;
for (var i = 0; i < texto.length; i++) {
    if (texto.charCodeAt(i) == number) { 
        alert("im backspace");
    }
}
```

So when a backspace is pressed on the textarea must be captured in the loop. I can guarantee you that in the var texto is receiving all the characters that the user enter inside the textarea. The problem, I'm sure, its the method charCodeAt(i), that I'm not using well. Any ideas?

Comment: Also 08 is an invalid octal number

Answer (score 2):

There is no char `ASCII 08 (Backspace)` enetered in the text box.

You should use [keydown](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/) event

```
$( "#'textEnv'" ).keydown(function( event ) {
    if ( event.which == 8 ) {
        // do sth
    }
});
```

in VanillaJS

```
document.getElementById('textEnv').onkeypress = function (e) { 
    e = e || window.event; 
    var charCode = e.charCode || e.keyCode, 
    if (charCode == 8) {
        // do sth
    }
};
```

Comment: There is no way to make it with charCodeAt(i)??

Comment: No, because `backspace` key is not added to string in your textbox

Comment: function comprobarTexto(e){
   var unicode=e.keyCode? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
   var texto = document.getElementById('textEnv').value;
   if(unicode==8){
     document.getElementById('textEnv').value = "";
    }
    if (texto.length > 10 || !texto.match(/^[0-9]+$/) && unicode!=8 ){
     alert("no puedes introducir mas de 10 caracteres y ha de ser numerico,revisa el numero");
    }
    
    
  }

Comment: this is my final function, it works i used the keyevent as you say

Answer (score 0):

You should use `keydown` event

Here your code rewritten

```
var text0 = document.getElementById('textEnv');
var number = 8;

text0.addEventListener("keydown", function() {
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;

    if( key == number )
        alert("im backspace");
});
```